# Connect to Access database protected with database password using UCanAccess

Tags: ucanaccess

I can connect to an Access database with UCanAccess from NetBeans 8, but now I need to specify database password in the connection properties. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

use following way,

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://path_to_your_db_file", your_user, your_password);
or
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://path_to_your_db_file;password=your_password");
```

Comment: Not is that password, Jet OLEDB:Database Password, My Question is How I can use this property in Java connection properties. Thank for your answer